# Get variable input value on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

not sure if this is even possible, I have a page with mutiple inputs,each input has a button. is there anyway of getting the inputs value on button click, without hardcoding the inputs id?

example

js

```
$('button').click(function () {


var inputcontent = $('input').prop('id');
console.log(inputcontent);

});
```

html

```
<input type="text" id="1">
<button type="button">Go!</button>
<input type="text" id="2">
<button type="button">Go!</button>
<input type="text" id="3">
<button type="button">Go!</button>
<input type="text" id="99">
<button type="button">Go!</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$('input').prop('id')` returns id of first matched element in selector. To target the input before each button, you need to use `.prev()` along with `$(this)`.
Try this:

```
$(this).prev().attr('id');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3MM7z/)**

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you explained the solution.

Comment: @FelixKling: was doing that only... :)

Comment: is there any way to .prev().prev()? i have a span just after the input and before the button

Answer (score 1):

You already doing it right, just change a little bit in your code. You have to find out the value of the input field, which is placed just before your button on which you will click. So your code should be:

```
 $('button').click(function () {


 var inputcontent = $(this).prev().prop('id');
 console.log(inputcontent);

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not targeting the item that you want the id from, the input just prior to the button. Use prev(0 to do that. In addition, id is really an attribute, not a property, so you should do this -

```
$('button').click(function () {

    var inputID = $(this).prev().attr('id'); // gets the id of the input that precedes the button
    console.log(inputID);

});
```

Comment: `$('input').prop('id')` returns the id.

Comment: Every DOM element has an ID property.

Comment: Yes it does, but it is not really proper because the id attribute isn't really a boolean, which is what prop() is designed for. From the docs - "The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes." http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: @JayBlanchard: this has noting to do with OPs problem.

Comment: Well, yes and no @MilindAnantwar I wrote (as you did) the code that would solve the OP's problem and in doing so I explained that id is really an attribute. Even you used attr() instead of prop(). I didn't say that using prop() was the problem, but illustrated that prev() would get the id attribute. Splitting hairs this morning? :) Heck, I even upvoted your answer!

Comment: @JayBlanchard: that is what i am saying,its great that you are mentioning this stuff in addition. but you should also tell the cause of main problem(which you did not) and solution to problem(which you did).

Answer (score 0):

This'll solve the issue

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var value = $(this).prev().val();
    console.log(value);
});
```